# Синхронизация от главной DB c несколькими другими DB в одном направлении

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет! Есть сайт, есть общая (главная) БД (на картинке General Login Database), и есть скажем 2-3 других БД которые работают со схожими (идентичными) идентификационными данными но содержащие в себе дополнительные поля которые уникальны только для этих баз данных (на картинки это Login Database 1 и L. db 2, помечены красным).

Располагается это все на 2-3 разных серверах. 
Изменить идентификационные данные не через "General DB" пользователь не может.
Вопрос как синхронизировать базы данных в одном направлении. То-есть если происходит изменение в General, то все эти изменения отправляются или ставятся в очередь на отправку (удаленный сервер может оказаться оффлайн) в Log.DB1, Log.DB2, итп.?

Использую:
ubuntu 16.04 
mysql 5.7
Тип таблиц MyISAM

[image: Показывает направление синхронизации]

Comment: Вынести блок подлежащих синхронизации данных в отдельную БД и настроить однонаправленную репликацию этой БД. Если к этим данным не привязаны каскадные операции (в т.ч. триггеры), то можно не создавать отдельную БД и ограничиться репликацией отдельных таблиц (ну то есть можно-то так в любом случае, но муторнее). Соответственно каждую таблицу с данными к репликации (и на мастере, и на слейве) придётся поделить на две со связью 1:1 - в одной только реплицируемые поля, во второй только нереплицируемые.

Comment: Спасибо кажется подходит, получилось так мастерdb-> слейвdb -> таблица-репликаций с парой нужных колонок-> тригеры -> живая таблица с лишними полями.